# how to fix `You are deubbging a release build of someproject.dll` in VS 2019 and debug

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual studio 2019, I have a nuget package installed in a web api project which I need to debug whose source code is in a seprate solution. I have followed these steps

1. I uninstalled this nuget package
2. Right clicked on solution and added existing project.
3. Right clicked on my web project and added reference and ticked this project in the reference manager window.

I was initially getting the following error and my break points were not getting hit. I clicked on `Disable Just My Code and Continue` but that did not help and I'm still unable to hit the break points. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have tried few solutions given in similar questions but nothing has helped.

[image]

Comment: If you use Project Reference to reference the nuget project, please make sure that the referenced project's pdb and dll file is under the main project output path.  Besides, make sure the nuget package is using Debug mode to build, then close VS Instance, delete the `bin` and `obj` folder of both the two projects and test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled this nuget package from the main web api project from my solution but then later on, realised it was also installed in another class library project. When I uninstalled it from all projects the error message was gone and I was able to debug as normal so the key point is to make sure to un-install the nuget package you want to debug from every project in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> how to fix `You are deubbging a release build of someproject.dll` in
>   VS 2019 and debug

I wonder if you use project reference to reference the nuget project into your main project.

If so,

**First**, it seems that you use Release mode to build the current referenced nuget project, so please change to use Debug mode.

`Build`-->`Configuration Manager` , make sure that every project uses **Debug**.

[image]

Try these suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** Right-click on both projects-->`Properties`-->`Build` --> `Advanced` --> `Debugging information` and set it to **full**.

Also, please make sure that these two options are checked.

[image]

**2)** Click `delete all breakpoints` under `Debug` menu.

**3)** Close VS Instance, delete `bin` ,`obj` folder on both projects and then restart your project again.

**4)** When you disable **Enable Just My Code** option under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`, you should check whether the main project has nuget project's `pdb` file and if not, you should copy the nuget project's `pdb` file into the main project's output path.

**5)** Then you can set the breakpoint and test again.